# ConcurrentBag of strings and using .Contains in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, thread-safety

Im using the ConcurrentBag to contain a list of strings. Occasionally it will contain a duplicate.

However im checking the contents of this before adding the new entry so it should never have a duplicate.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> SystemFiles = PopulateSystemFiles();
ConcurrentBag<string> SystemNames = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

Parallel.ForEach(SystemFiles, file =>
{
    string name = GetSystemName(file.Value);

    if (!SystemNames.Contains(name))
    {
        SystemNames.Add(name);
    }
});
```

My assumpion is that the .Contains method is not thread safe. Am i correct?

Comment: can't you just add it all and call a Distinct() function?

Comment: Enumerating a ConcurrentBag is extremely inefficient. Use a ConcurrentDictionary instead

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim Yes, there are a few options. But im curious why a collection specifically designed to be threadsafe, isnt threadsafe.

Comment: The collection *is* threadsafe, as in "using it concurrently won't corrupt its state". It doesn't make your "contains then add" operation atomic. It's your code that isn't threadsafe

Comment: @KevinGosse Thanks. So sticking a lock around my IF condition should sort that?

Comment: It would, yes. But if you use a lock, then you can use a non-threadsafe collection such as HashSet. In the end, I think you should just replace your ConcurrentBag with a ConcurrentDictionary (it's a bit awkward as you will be using only the key, not the value, but it's fine)

Comment: @KevinGosse Wouldnt the same issue occur when im checking the ConcurrentDictionary contains a key and then adding it?

Comment: As @KevinGosse said, if you want this to be an atomic, thread-safe operation, use a ConcurrentDictionary and forget about the value. You don't check if the dictionary has the key, you use `TryAdd`

Comment: @CathalMF ConcurrentDictionary has a TryAdd method that does the "if not contains then add" operation in an atomic way

Comment: @KevinGosse Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ConcurrentBag` is threadsafe, but your code isn't:

```
if (!SystemNames.Contains(name))
{
    SystemNames.Add(name);
}
```

`Contains` will execute in a thread-safe way, then `Add` will also execute in a thread-safe way, but you have no guarantee that an item haven't been added in-between.

For your needs, I recommend using a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead. Just ignore the value as you won't need it.

```
var SystemNames = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();
```

Then use the `TryAdd` method to do the "if not contains then add" in a single atomic operation:

```
SystemNames.TryAdd(name, true);
```